# Autocad opens empty file, although there are files in it

Tags: autocad

I was working on a file yesterday for more than 8 hours, then save it and close it.
Now I double-clicked it and it opened a new file to me, but I can see, that in the file, there are still some things drawn.

A picture below might come handy for this.

[image]

And when I open (double-click) the file, this comes out:
[image]

I really want my file back as I don't want to spend another day to get on the same spot, I was yesterday.

PS: The file is 64kb large, so there must be somethings in it.

I'm using Autocad2013 and yes, I've tried to unscroll to find the objects, also double-clicked on the mouse wheel to center everything and ctrl+A to mark everything. Nothing happened.

I noticed this once before; is it possible, that AutoCAD does have this glitch when you save a file with name Drawing1.dwg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drawing has somehow become corrupted, the `.bak` file saved in the same directory represents a backup of the drawing taken at regular intervals defined within the options of your application.

You can view the contents of this backup by renaming the file extension from `.bak` to `.dwg` and opening the file in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 0):

I have students that have the same problem in windows 11. It seems to be more of a ACAD - Windows interface problem.

Work around is to open autoCAD first, then go to "open file" button and click that, and then to open the file manually by looking for it through the AutoCAD interface and open file menu and clicking the file that way. If you open the file that way, then all of a sudden the content in the file is shown perfectly normally. It's only if you try and open a file directly through windows by double clicking it in explorer that the file appears to be empty.

I haven't found the root cause of this problem though.